# Preview a Trigger Send without publishing

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript, rest

Is there a way to trigger an email using a landing page?

The only way to see the changes to an email that is part of a Trigger Send is by publishing the changes. But I would like to use a landing page to that a QA person can verify before going live.

What's the easiest way to do so? Via a rest call or using ampscript and landing pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [Send Preview](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/send_preview/) on the Email Definition itself without republishing the Triggered Send Definition.

You can also set up a [User-Initiated Send Definition](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/) that references the Email Definition and send to a seed audience without republishing the Triggered Send Definition.

Some terminology:

- **Template** - an email with pre-defined content area placeholders to be populated in the Email Definition
- **Email Definition** - the email in it's most basic form (raw HTML or based on a Template)
- **Triggered Send Definition** - the email waiting to be sent to an audience supplied in an API call
- **User-Initiated Send Definition** - an email plus a predefined audience (List, Filter or Sendable Data Extension)

Comment: I have so many clients that only want a copy of the latest emails, they don't need access to ET and I don't want to go each time to create a Send Preview. It is time consuming. The User-Initiated Definition may end up being the same as Trigger send since it has to be manually trigger. I would like to create a landing page where the user selects the email they want to preview, then input their email address and finally get a copy.

Comment: Sweet. Did this work for you?  If so, would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).